# Does anyone actually know how to fix these errors?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to deal with these erros? I'm new to Javascript and I'm currently trying to learn some api stuff for esri. I honestly don't understand what these errors mean or how to go about fixing them. Here are the errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b3c3566f3e1c4b6b8035185fba217f54?f=json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

q {message: "Unable to load file://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/…b3c3566f3e1c4b6b8035185fba217f54?f=json status: 0", response: Object, status: 0, responseText: "", xhr: XMLHttpRequest…}
```

Here is the code that made them.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create a Web Map</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
        <style>
            html, body, #mapDiv, .map.container{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad:true };</script>
        <!--<script> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null </script> perhaps this could be part of a solution-->
        <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14compact/"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            require([
                "esri/map",
                "esri/arcgis/utils",
                "dojo/domReady!"
                ], function(Map, arcgisUtils){
                arcgisUtils.createMap( "b3c3566f3e1c4b6b8035185fba217f54", "mapDiv").then(function (response) {
                    map = response.map;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great. I have to say I am completely lost at this point.

Comment: Do not run on the file protocol. Learn about CORS

Comment: @Steve Is browser chrome / chromium ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the URL:

```
file://www.arcgis.com/.....
```

AJAX doesn't work on the file system.  (Nor is that likely to be a valid file system path anyway, it looks like it *should* be a website.)  It works on web servers.

Presumably you're opening this HTML file directly from your file system.  Instead, host it on a web server (which can be your local computer) and open it through HTTP.

There may yet be other concerns regarding your AJAX requests.  Perhaps you're not specifying the URL correctly (there isn't a complete enough example here to know for certain), or perhaps even once you're making a request to a web server it may be a cross-domain request.  We can't really know.  But at the very least, this has to run on a web server.

Comment: _"AJAX doesn't work on the file system."_ ? url at Question does not appear valid , though ajax can be used at `file:` protocol

Comment: How do I know when to use a server and when to use a file? A similar piece of code executed without an errors when I ran it from a file.